# Searching for objects within nested array: how to return only found objects and parent elements?

Tags: python, json, flask, pymongo

Here's an excerpt from `pictures` MongoDB collection:

```json
[
  {
    "_id": "57582b6b",
    "source": "integration",
    "url": "https://example.com/images/51/landscapes-polar.xml",
    "pictures": [
      {
        "name": "pines",
        "version": "2"
      },
      {
        "name": "penguins",
        "version": "1"
      },
      {
        "name": "pineapple",
        "version": "7"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "57582b6d",
    "source": "customer",
    "url": "https://example.com/images/15/nature.xml",
    "pictures": [
      {
        "name": "mountains",
        "version": "2"
      },
      {
        "name": "pines",
        "version": "1"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "57582b6c",
    "source": "qa",
    "url": "https://example.com/image/32/landscapes.xml",
    "pictures": [
      {
        "name": "alps",
        "version": "1"
      },
      {
        "name": "pineapple",
        "version": "7"
      },
      {
        "name": "pines",
        "version": "3"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

My main concern is to find specific `names` from inside of nested `pictures` array. When names matching partial query string are found, they should be preserved in `pictures` array and displayed along with `pictures`'s array parent. Using PyMongo library, I was able to retrieve queried data using this function:

```py
import re
from flask import Flask, jsonify

from controller.database import client, database_name, temp_collection


app = Flask(__name__)
db = client[database_name]
collection = db[temp_collection]


@app.route('/component/find/<picture_name>', methods=['GET'])
def get_component(picture_name):
    pattern = re.compile(picture_name, re.IGNORECASE)

    pipeline = [
        {"$unwind": "$pictures"},
        {"$match": {"pictures.name": {"$regex": pattern}}},
        {"$group": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "url": {"$first": "$url"},
            "source": {"$first": "$source"},
            "pictures": {"$addToSet": "$pictures"},
            "root": {"$first": "$$ROOT"}
        }},
        {"$replaceRoot": {
            "newRoot": {
                "$mergeObjects": ["$root", {"pictures": "$pictures"}]
            }
        }},
        {"$project": {
            "_id": {"$toString": "$_id"},
            "url": 1,
            "source": 1,
            "pictures": 1
        }}
    ]

    result = list(collection.aggregate(pipeline))

    if result:
        return jsonify(result)
    else:
        return jsonify({"message": "Component with picture '{}' not found.".format(picture_name)}), 404


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

However, retrieved data only contains one-element `pictures` arrays, instead of putting there all matching objects.

In other words, this is what I'd like to get:

```json
[
  {
    "_id": "57582b6b",
    "source": "integration",
    "url": "https://example.com/51/landscapes-polar.xml",
    "pictures": [
      {
        "name": "pines",
        "version": "2"
      },
      {
        "name": "pineapple",
        "version": "7"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "57582b6d",
    "source": "customer",
    "url": "https://example.com/15/nature.xml",
    "pictures": [
      {
        "name": "pines",
        "version": "1"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "57582b6c",
    "source": "qa",
    "url": "https://example.com/image/32/landscapes.xml",
    "pictures": [
      {
        "name": "pineapple",
        "version": "7"
      },
      {
        "name": "pines",
        "version": "3"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

and this is what I get now:

```json
[
  {
    "_id": "57582b6b",
    "source": "integration",
    "url": "https://example.com/51/landscapes-polar.xml",
    "pictures": [
      {
        "name": "pines",
        "version": "2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "57582b6d",
    "source": "customer",
    "url": "https://example.com/15/nature.xml",
    "pictures": [
      {
        "name": "pines",
        "version": "1"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "57582b6c",
    "source": "qa",
    "url": "https://example.com/image/32/landscapes.xml",
    "pictures": [
      {
        "name": "pineapple",
        "version": "7"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

How to make sure all matching `pictures` objects get pushed to proper arrays? (Using `$push` instead of `$addToSet` returns the same results.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Mongo Playground, I was able to build up the query step by step and found out that removing some markup results in responding with the contents I wanted. The Flask app should be set up this way:

```py
import re
from flask import Flask, jsonify

from controller.database import client, database_name, temp_collection


app = Flask(__name__)
db = client[database_name]
collection = db[temp_collection]


@app.route('/component/find/<picture_name>', methods=['GET'])
def get_component(picture_name):
    pattern = re.compile(picture_name, re.IGNORECASE)

    pipeline = [
        {"$unwind": "$pictures"},
        {"$match": {"pictures.name": {"$regex": pattern}}},
        {"$group": {
            "_id": {"$toString": "$_id"}, # convert _id to str
            "url": {"$first": "$url"},
            "source": {"$first": "$source"},
            "pictures": {"$addToSet": "$pictures"}
        }}
    ]

    result = list(collection.aggregate(pipeline))

    if result:
        return jsonify(result)
    else:
        return jsonify({"message": "Component with picture '{}' not found.".format(picture_name)}), 404


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```